# How to use python to move the mouse in circles

Tags: python, mouse, ctypes, mousemove, pyautogui

I'm trying to write a script in python, to automatically force the movement of the mouse pointer without the user's input (it quits through the keyboard), and experimenting with PyAutoGUI, PyUserInput and ctypes, I've been figuring out ways to move the pointer with constant speed, instead of having it teleport across the screen(I need the user to be able to see the path it makes). However, I need it to be able to perform curves, and particularly, circles, and I haven't found a way to do so with the aforementioned libraries. Does anybody know of a way to code them into making the mouse describe circles across the screen at constant speed, instead of just straight lines? Thank you beforehand for any input or help you may provide.

Comment: Approximate the circle as n straight line segments, with n large enough so it looks like a circle? Or actually teleport it to n equidistant points on the circle, it will seem like smooth motion if n is large enough.

Answer (score 5):

This is my attempt at making circle at the center of the screen of radius R - also note if I don't pass parameter *duration* then the mouse pointer moves to the next coordinates instantly. So for a circle divided into 360 parts you can set the pace using a modulus.

```
import pyautogui
import math

# Radius 
R = 400
# measuring screen size
(x,y) = pyautogui.size()
# locating center of the screen 
(X,Y) = pyautogui.position(x/2,y/2)
# offsetting by radius 
pyautogui.moveTo(X+R,Y)

for i in range(360):
    # setting pace with a modulus 
    if i%6==0:
       pyautogui.moveTo(X+R*math.cos(math.radians(i)),Y+R*math.sin(math.radians(i)))
```

Comment: pyautogui's MINIMUM_DURATION is 0.1 seconds, so this takes 6 seconds to draw a not so smooth circle. Is there a way to draw a smoother circle in less than a seond?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this using sin, cos, and tan. (I haven't been able to test this code yet, It might not work.)

```
Import math
Import pyautogui
def circle(radius = 5, accuracy = 360, xpos=0, ypos=0, speed = 5):
    local y
    local x
    local angle
    angle = 360/accuracy
    local CurAngle
    CurAngle = 0
    x = []
    y = []
    sped = speed/accuracy
    for i in range(accuracy):
        x.append(xpos + radius*math.sin(math.radians(CurAngle)))
        y.append(ypos + radius*math.cos(math.radians(CurAngle)))
        CurAngle += angle
    for i in len(x):
        pyautogui.moveTo(x[i], y[i], duration = sped)
```

You put this near the top of your script, and pass arguments like this:
circle(radius, accuracy, xpos, ypos, speed)
Radius controls the width of the circle
Accuracy controls how many equi-distant points the circle is to be broken up into, setting accuracy to 4 will put 4 invisible points along the circle for the mouse to travel tom which will make a square, not a circle, 5 makes a pentagon, 6 a hexagon, etc.. the bigger the radius, the bigger you will want the accuracy
Xpos controls the x position of where the circle is centered
Ypos controls the y position of where the circle is centered
Speed controls how many seconds you want it to take to draw the circle.
Hope this helps :) Would you mind elaborating what you are wanting when you say 'curves'

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui as pg

resolution = pg.size()
radius = 300 # Circle radius
duration = 0.1 # Duration of each move(mouse speed)
steps = 20 # Number of 'moves' or points on the circle

mid_x = resolution[0] / 2
mid_y = resolution[1] / 2

def GetXnY(angle):
    x = radius * math.sin(math.pi * 2 * angle / 360)
    y = radius * math.cos(math.pi * 2 * angle / 360)
    return (x, y)

def DoACircle():
    angle = 0
    while angle  <= 360:
        x, y = GetXnY(angle)
        pg.moveTo((mid_x + x), (mid_y - y), duration = duration)
        angle = angle + (360/steps)
           
DoACircle()
```

Comment: Pascal case is for classes, functions follow sneak case